# nginx: server fail to restart after adding server block

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

Am trying to run `nginx` on `AWS` `Ubuntu` everything works fine until i add the `server{}` block then restarting `nginx` fail.
This the code am adding inside the `http` block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ec2-00-00-00-000.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://thumbor;
    }
}
```

Then i try to restart using  `nginx service nginx restart` and, i got this error:

```
Restarting nginx nginx      [fail]
```

Comment: Check the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Open your root conf and ensure that you have **info** in error_log. This will log everything.

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
Reload your configuration using nginx -s reload
```

Then see the tail of error log...

```
tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

It should give you pointers about what's going on.